# Match phone country code with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to implement a javascript function to replace country code part of a phone number.

The input is +90 (533) 333 33 33 and I want to replace +90 part with javascript. I tried do write a regex but I couldn't succeed.

```
/^\++[a-z]+\s$/
```

**EDIT : Final solution**

```
$("#ddlCountry").change(function () {
    if ($("#tMobile").val() == '') {
        $("#tMobile").val("+" + $(this).find(":selected").attr("CountryCode")
        + " ");
    } else {
        $("#tMobile").val($("#tMobile").val().replace(/^(\+\d*)/,
        "+" + $(this).find(":selected").attr("CountryCode")));
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you use `[a-z]` when you're matching *numbers*?

Comment: That regular expression would match one or more `+` followed by one or more `a-z` followed by exactly one piece of whitespace. I don't see how it could match `90`. Nor does it include any commands to do any replacement. Can you include more of your code? This doesn't look anywhere near enough...

Comment: Because [0-9] didn't work also.. I'm not good with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pattern should match any [country code](http://countrycode.org/), assuming there's always a non-digit character between the country code and whatever number comes next: `/^(\+\d*)/`

```
var phoneNumber = "+90 (533) 333 33 33";
phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/^(\+\d*)/, '+852');
alert(phoneNumber);
```

([Try it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdleyEskridge/cTEqT/))

**Edit:**
Okay... this is a bit silly, you can also do this:

```
var phoneNumber = "+90 (533) 333 33 33";
phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/^(\+)(\d*)(.*)/, '$1852$3');
alert(phoneNumber);
```

([Try it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdleyEskridge/6AqgA/))

I was trying to make it unnecessary to include the plus sign in the new country code, but I can't find a way of doing that other than what I've shown above. Essentially, it uses three capture groups: one for the plus sign, one for the country code, and one for the rest of the phone number. In the new country code, I sandwiched the country code itself in between `$1` and `$3`, which translates to:

Replace the old phone number with a new phone number consisting of the first capture group (the plus sign) followed by the new country code ("852") followed by the rest of the phone number (" (533) 333 33 33").

Comment: @Hasan, I deleted this answer while I searched for a more satisfactory solution. I'll go ahead and undeleted it, though. I'm currently trying to figure out how to replace only the digits in the country code, and not the plus sign as well. The code above works, but it requires that the new country code contains a plus sign.

Answer (score 2):

as long as you can guarantee that your input will be in that format:

```
var phone = '+90 (533) 333 33 33';
    phone.replace(/^\+[0-9]{2}/,'xyz')
```

Before: +90 (533) 333 33 33

After: xyz (533) 333 33 33

Comment: Oops, sorry use this `/^\+[0-9]{1,}/`. It will match country codes with 1-3 digits.

Answer (score 2):

This is considerably faster than regular expressions.

```
function replaceCountryCode ( number, replaceWith ) {
    return replaceWith + number.substr( number.indexOf( ' ' ) );
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/XEBdP/
Performance: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-indexof-replace

[image]