# Drop leading "0" from phone number and replace with +44

Tags: javascript

I have a html form and i need the 0 dropping from the phone number and +44 adding on to it. Is there a way to do this with script so that it submits properly on the form submission.

```html
  <form action="https://123.com" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);"> 
   <input name="PhoneNumber" type="tel" required="">
   <input name="myButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
```

Comment: Consider using `.replace`? Please make sure the phone number is stored as a string, and consider using regex to match the leading zero. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697008/match-phone-country-code-with-javascript

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sounds like a valid answer. :)

Comment: @Ivar I'm only in the mood for suggestions ... 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `substring` to take everything from the first character onwards and prepend "+44"

```js
const phoneNumber = "01234567890";
const asIntl = "+44" + phoneNumber.substring(1)
console.log(asIntl)
```

You can use this

```js
function checkForm(f) {
  const phoneNumberField = f.querySelector("[name='PhoneNumber']");
  if(phoneNumberField.value.startsWith("0")){
    phoneNumberField.value = "+44" + phoneNumberField.value.substring(1);
  }
  
  return false; // Just for demo to stop the form submitting
}
```

```html
<form action="https://123.com" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">
  <input name="PhoneNumber" type="tel" required="">
  <input name="myButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

on form submit as follows:

Answer (score 3):

You can use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for that:

```js
var phoneNumber = '0123 456789';

console.log(phoneNumber.replace(/^0/,'+44 '));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. And how would i get this to run on my form and submit properly?

Comment: Glad to help. I think this answer is solving your original question. Please post a new question for your next requirement instead of changing the original post.